# Metro application directly focuses on my first field

Tags: c#, xaml, microsoft-metro, winrt-xaml

I'm creating this test Metro application using Windows 8, VS2012, C# and XAML. There are different `TextBox` in the application page arranged in a `StackPanel`. When the application is launched the focus is on the first `TextBox`.

I was wondering how to "deactivate" this.

Here's a pic, as you can see the first field is focused (color changed and ToolTip displayed).

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One simple fix for this is place something to catch it first with `IsTabStop="True"` with a 0 `Opacity` which is a bit hacky but the only way I know. So something like;

```
<TextBox IsTabStop="True" Opacity="0" Height="1" Width="1"/>
<!-- Then the rest of your content like your other TextBox stuff -->
```

Answer (score 1):

When your UI is loaded you can remove focus from the `TextBox` by applying a **Programmatic** focus state to any other control.

Imagine that you have a `Button` named myButton. You can:

```
myButton.Focus(FocusState.Programmatic);
```

You cannot however use `FocusState.Unfocused` state to remove focus from the TextBlock because it is not allowed and will throw an exception.

Comment: thank you :), i accepted the Chris W.'s answer since it requires only modifying the XAML side of the project instead of this one where I would have to modify the .xaml.cs file as well.

Comment: @enibundo I like Chris W. hack because it is fast to implement but this way you won't need to change your XAML because you have other elements to focus for sure (there is no need to create myButton in your XAML)